# How to do basic arithmetic in Truffle testing using web3.js

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, truffle

I'm currently using Truffle to test smart contracts, but having difficulty with basic arithmetic.

If I try to add two numbers:

```js
const firstNumber = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether'); // 1000000000000000000
const sum = firstNumber + 100
```

The result is like when two strings are attached `1000000000000000000100`.

I tried converting `firstNumber.toString()` or using `const { toBN } = web3.utils;` but all have the same result.

I tried using `add` or `mul` like some examples [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/42175/60514), but my Truffle simply says those methods don't exist.

I'm using Truffle v5.3.14 (core: 5.3.14) and Web3.js v1.4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'1' is a string so you will receive string from [.toWei](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#towei). You can convert String to BN and use [.add](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-utils.html#id48). For example:

```
const firstNumber = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether'); // 1000000000000000000
const sum = web3.utils.toBN(firstNumber).add(web3.utils.toBN('100')).toString();
```